# Recursion on multidimensional object of arrays - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am creating a function that works with recursion that returns an array in any order of the full names of the family members w/c pass the test.

As an example:

```
var myFamily = {
  'firstName': 'Robert',
  'lastName': 'Doel',
  'location': 'New York, NY',
  'children': [
    {
      'firstName': 'Ricardo',
      'lastName': 'Doel',
      'location': 'Austin, TX',
      'children': [
        {
          'firstName': 'Jimmy',
          'lastName': 'Bondoc',
          'location': 'San Diego, CA',
          'children': []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Mike',
      'lastName': 'Watanabe',
      'location': 'San Diego, CA',
      'children': []
    }
  ]
};

familyTest(myFamily, function(item){
  return item.location === 'San Diego, CA';
});
```

Right now I am trying my best to get my code to do recursion but some reason, I think I am not doing it right:

```
var familyTest = function (familyObj, test) {

  var result = [];

  for(var prop in familyObj){
    if(truthTest(familyObj[prop])){
       result.push(familyObj[firstName] + ' ' + familyObj[lastName]);
    }
   var children = familyObj['children'];
   for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        if(truthTest(children[i].prop)){
          result.push(children[i].firstName + ' ' + children[i].lastName);
        }
   }
    }

return familyTest(children);
};
```

Any idea how can I fix my code to make it work using recursion?

Comment: Recursion is a function that calls itself.  Nowhere do I see the `familyTest` function being called here.  Example: `foo = function(bar) { if (!bar) { return foo.count; } else { foo.count++; foo(Math.abs(parseInt(bar))-1) } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this recursively, we can do something simple like this:

```js
function filterTree(obj, results, test) {
  if (test(obj))
    results.push(obj);
  
  if (obj.children)
    for (let child of obj.children)
      filterTree(child, results, test) 
}

var myFamily = {
  'firstName': 'Robert',
  'lastName': 'Doel',
  'location': 'New York, NY',
  'children': [
    {
      'firstName': 'Ricardo',
      'lastName': 'Doel',
      'location': 'Austin, TX',
      'children': [
        {
          'firstName': 'Jimmy',
          'lastName': 'Bondoc',
          'location': 'San Diego, CA',
          'children': []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Mike',
      'lastName': 'Watanabe',
      'location': 'San Diego, CA',
      'children': []
    }
  ]
};

var results = [];

filterTree(myFamily, results, function(person) {
  return person.location === 'San Diego, CA'
})

// results will now contain all family members that match the test.
console.log(results);

// however, since we only want the names of these family members, we will map over these properties
var fullNames = results.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
})

console.log(fullNames);
```

Comment: How do you put fullnames map function inside recursion function so you can automatically pull up the names instead of having a separate function for each?

Comment: instead of doing `results.push(obj)`, we would instead do: `results.push(obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName)`